# MYSQL will it take long to read through a database?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

Let's say I have a table called `comments` in my database. Each comment has an id, an assigned post and its data (the actual text submitted by the user.) Let's say I have 10,000 posts and each post has 10 comments. That's a total of 100,000 comments. If a user loads up a post and its comments.

Will the code I use to load the comments read though all one hundred thousand comments to pick out the one's with a postID of (lets say:) 11 or will it instantly be able to see that there is 10 comments with the postID of 11 and pick them out (which would be a lot quicker than looking through 100,000 comments. What does MySql do in this scenario?

Comment: If it's indexed properly it will use the index and not scan all the records, if it's not then it will. I recommend searching for information on database indexing.

Comment: To get answers to questions such as this one, awesome guys who maintain MySQL created the [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html). To avoid theory and what not, simply use `EXPLAIN` and you'll get your answers. You haven't posted your table schema nor the query. It's possible it scans 100k rows, it's possible it's doing less - ask it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the following in the table definition (along with other columns):

```
post_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,  -- for JOINing to Posts table
comment_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(post_id, comment_id),  -- clusters all the comments together for a post
INDEX(comment_id)  -- keeps AUTO_INCREMENT happy
```

And use `ENGINE=InnoDB` so that the `PRIMARY KEY` is clustered with the data.

```
SELECT ... 
    WHERE post_id = 123
      AND comment_id > 0   -- see note below
    ORDER BY comment_id ASC
    LIMIT 10
```

With this, all 10 comments will come from one block (or possibly a very small number of blocks), thereby be as efficient as possible.

Since your next question will be about finding the 'next' 10 comments, I have jumped ahead.  Recommended reading:  [*This*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/pagination-optimization/) .  "Remember where you left off with the first 10 comments, then change the `0` to the last `comment_id` found.

I have given you a lot of keywords to research and understand.  Please study the manuals before coming back with your next question.